# Battery pack not charging

Tags: battery-charging

I have a couple of lithium 100 Ah 12 V batteries connected in series to get the 24 V required by an inverter (I've got a Vervor hybrid system with charger/MPPT/inverter all in one).

I'm connecting them using [this battery equalizer](https://es.aliexpress.com/item/1005005925888633.html). After a couple of successful charges to approx 60% of the full capacity (at 35 A and 40 A), now the batteries are not charging anymore :( Something to mention is that one of the batteries was discharged (having about 11 V) for about 5 weeks, and also that by accident, both batteries in series got shorted for a moment with a cable :/ before the first charge, I equalized the voltages of both with a power resistor until the difference was like 20 mV.

What I'm seeing now when trying to charge them, is that the equalizer shows a very high voltage of 15 V on one of them and 13.3 V on the other. Could this 15 V be the reason why the batteries are not being charged?  The maximum charging voltage for a single battery is 14.5 V according to battery manufacturer. The batteries are these https://es.eco-worthy.com/collections/12v/products/bateria-litio-lifepo4-12v-100ah

What could be happening? How can I check if the batteries are ok?

Comment: What batteries they are? Make, modem, manual, datasheet, any info? Did the batteries have internal protection circuitry? Did it trip due to overcurrent from short circuit? If they are li-ion batteries, the cells have too much voltage. If they are some other than li-ion, please mention what batteries they are.

Comment: Thanks! I just added the link of the batteries